# NSTextView - using up/down arrows moves paragraphs not lines

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have an app that runs on iOS and uses UITextView to display rich text, and also runs on Mac and uses NSTextView to display rich text. These are separate apps, but with a lot of shared code. In both cases, the {NS,UI}Textview is programmatically created and placed on a canvas.

{NS,UI}TextView will wrap long lines of text as required. Long lines are called paragraphs and have NSParagraphStyles that can be applied across the whole paragraph (line spacing, head indent etc). Each paragraph is delineated by a "\n" character (or one of the Unicode equivalents). Paragraphs wrap across multiple lines, if required.

On iOS, when you have a long paragraph covering multiple lines... if you use the down/up arrow keys, the cursor moves up and down by *lines* (i.e. possibly within the same paragraph), which is as you expect.

On the Mac, with the same setup, the up/down arrow keys move the cursor up and down by *paragraphs* (i.e. multiple lines), which is very much *not* what you expect.

I have attached videos of the two cursor movements so you can see what happens.

I use the same code to create the {NS,UI}TextView, and I can't see why there is a difference.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I have not interfered with the arrow key handlers in any way (although I do implement textViewDidChangeSelection: in the delegate, and can confirm that the selection is changing per my comments above).

Any ideas would be most appreciated!
Thx.

*iOS Cursor Down in a UITextView.*

[image: iOS Cursor Down]

*Mac Cursor Down in an NSTextView.*

[image: Mac Cursor Down]

Comment: It's strange, I pasted a long text into NStextfield on macOS, it's the same as what you have shown on iOS. Any chance you write a simple showcase app that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: I get the same result as you, so there is some setting inside NSTextView that is causing this as a side effect. I dont know what it could be...

Comment: Found it! It was an errant calculation in the delegate function DoCommandBySelector. I'm sure I hadn't changed it, so I've decided it must have suffered from bit-rot. I'm so sure, I'm not going to look at the git history :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! It was an errant calculation in the delegate function DoCommandBySelector.